# Spring security protect pointcut using bean profiles duplicate definition

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-tool-suite, spring-bean

When using Spring security, I'd like to define different acceptable roles for a method per profile being ran. The problem I'm having is the protect-pointcut definition does not appear to accept context placeholders (doesn't translate if using access="${secured.role}). If I put the security element within each bean profile, STS gives a warning saying that multiple global-security-method elements exist. I understand why this is so, as if I ran two profiles that both loaded this, both would load. Although if I only ran one profile (which is my intent) only the correct one would load.

Here is my definitions:

```
<beans profile="security-ad">
    <security:global-method-security>
        <security:protect-pointcut access="ROLE_THAT_ROLE" expression="execution(* com.test.service.TestServiceImpl.testSecuredMethod(..))"/>
    </security:global-method-security>
</beans>

<beans profile="security-tam">
    <security:global-method-security>
        <security:protect-pointcut access="ROLE_THIS_ROLE" expression="execution(* com.test.service.TestServiceImpl.testSecuredMethod(..))"/>
    </security:global-method-security>
</beans>

<beans profile="security-embedded">
    <security:global-method-security>
        <security:protect-pointcut access="ROLE_ADMIN" expression="execution(* com.test.service.TestServiceImpl.testSecuredMethod(..))"/>
    </security:global-method-security>
</beans>
```

Is there any way to achieve profile-based roles within the security definitions while still making STS happy? This DOES run, it just has an error in the project, which is not acceptable to me...

Comment: STS will also barf on defining a bean with the same ID using bean profiles. This is basically just a flaw of the eclipse xml validator. Just ignore the warnings, at runtime it will work. Instead of xml you could also enable annotation processing, which would allow you to write expressions this allows for a more powerful/flexible solution.

Comment: Is there any way to disable validation on a single XML file in the project? I really hate having errors in the project, even if I know they are erroneous. I'd rather not disable validation everywhere as validation is helpful, just wanting to get around this one specific issue.

Comment: Can you file an enhancement request and attach a sample project that reproduces the issue at https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS ? That would be great. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: It is created. Thanks Martin.